# C# calling unmanaged code

Tags: c#, unmanaged, return, lpbyte

I am trying to call unmanaged code using C#.

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LPBYTE DataReceived(LPBYTE signals)
{
   LPBYTE test;
   *(WORD*)(test) = 0x0C;
   *(WORD*)(test + 2) = 0x1000;

   return test;
   // I even tried returning 0x00 only; and I was still getting the exception

}
```

C# code

```
internal sealed class Test
{
    [DllImport("testlib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern byte[] DataReceived(byte[] signals);

}

// signals is byte[] too
byte[] foo = Test.DataReceived(signals);

//exception that occurs 
 A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException
```

I am having another function which returns an int value just fine, I guess it's related to LPBYTE itself. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to use

```
internal sealed class Test
{
    [DllImport("testlib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr DataReceived(byte[] signals);

}
```

Note that when you call it, you will need to use [`Marshall.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx) to get the data out, but this will require that you know the length of the data.

```
IntPtr fooPtr = Test.DataRecieved(signals);
var foo = new byte[LENGTH];
Marshall.Copy(fooPtr, foo, 0, LENGTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

adam nathans book is the bible on this

hang on: what exactly is the return value of this function. Its a pointer to what?

test points to random address, then you poke data where test points

What do you want to return?

If you must return a pointer then declare function as returning intptr then call Marshall to copy bytes. THen you need to decide if you need to free the returned buffer

Answer (score 0):

How should the .NET marshaller know how much data needs to be copied from the returned array into a managed array instance?

You may want to try and accept an `IntPtr` as result, then use the `Marshal` class to copy the data.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the pinvoke interop assistant here:

http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/

It will automatically generate pinvoke signatures for you.